# Unit Testing a FuelPHP Model

Tags: php, unit-testing, activerecord, fuelphp

So I have a very simple (at least right now it is) model that returns a contact via it's primary key ID:

```
class Model_Contact extends \Fuel\Core\Model
{
    public function get_by_id($contact_id)
    {
        return Entity_Contact::find_by_pk($contact_id);
    }
}
```

The `Entity_Contact` class looks like this (irrelevant array content omitted):

```
class Entity_Contact extends \Core\Entity_Base
{
    protected static $_table_name = 'contacts';
    protected static $_properties = array(...);
    protected static $_public_settable_properties = array(...);
    protected static $_rules = array(...);
}
```

Note: `\Core\Entity_Base` extends `\Fuel\Core\Model_Crud`

I might use this in a controller like so:

```
$model = new Model_Contact();
$contact = $model->get_by_id(4);
```

I know that in order to unit test this, I should mock out the actual database call (`Entity_Contact::find_by_pk`), but I'm not sure how to do this. Since I'm using Fuel's `Model_crud` functionality (where the DB accessors are actually a part of the domain object model), I'm not sure that I can completely mock the database---or maybe I'm missing something.

So the question: how would you write a test for `Model_Contact::get_by_id()`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't used Fuel, but it seems to be more procedural than OOP, with static calls everywhere, using classes as bags of functions [1]. For something to be testable, it has to be written with explicit dependencies so you can inject the actual objects or fake ones (mocks or stubs). You should take a look at other frameworks like [Symfony2](http://symfony.com) where everything is easily testable, because it's based on this principle. [1]: https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.4/develop/classes/model/crud.php  (check out the method 'find'. It calls \DB::select(), etc)

Comment: You're right, and as I've been digging into this I've found that it isn't very testable. In fact, MVC as we know it today with what is preached in the various frameworks' docs completely ignore testability.

Comment: Let me insist =p, Symfony2 and Silex have implemented everything in a testable way. Nothing is forced on you, you don't even have to extend from Controller if you don't want to (we only do that for convenience). And the Entity objects are plain old php objects, no base model to extend, because we use the Data Mapper pattern. On the other hand, it can be a bit difficult to get started (comparing to other frameworks), but that's because there's a lot to know about web development, and Symfony2 covers most aspects of it, always using the best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test may have to create the objects so you can test your methods.

1. Create the objects that get stored to the database.
2. Test get_by_id
3. Delete your created object

It's not the most glorious thing in the world, but it would accomplish testing your method... meh?

Comment: Yes, since I cannot mock the actual database accessor object, this is my only option. Bah humbug.

Answer (score 1):

You can mock it easily if you use AspectMock.
https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock